# python2.7 function range() memory leak on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

When I use range function, it occupied memory forever, even if I del and run gc.collect()

```
import gc
import time
a = range(int(1e8))
del a
gc.collect()
time.sleep(30)
```

I use htop to monitor and see that they occupied a lot of memory forever. It only happen on ubuntu16.04 (macos is not).
Any idea why it happen?

Comment: In python 2.7 `range` creates a list (so you're allocating a lot of memory when you define `a`). Use `xrange` to have lazy iteration and avoiding to allocate the list of integers between 0 and `1e8` instead. Python 3 replaces `range` to always behave like `xrange`.

Comment: @GPhilo I have mention (and also in the code) I have delete the variable keep this range, so it mean I already delete this list.

Comment: CPython frees memory internally, but it does not give it back to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Klaus D. answer, I figure it out.

Range create a list of pointer, each pointer point to an object. Del "a" will free that list and give back memory. It also dell all int object, but these small object not give back to OS because python manage small memory allocate by itself.